# Pandas - vectorize "any element in a column within the next timeframe is True"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

So I have a dataframe that consists of a *datetime* index and a *boolean* column;
is there an effective (non-loop) way of doing the following operation:

**for** each row, find if **any** of the boolean values in the target column **is True** within the next **1 hour** timeframe.

For example:

[image]

Now I have a loop for this, but will be grateful for any suggestions on how to improve it.

```
pd.DataFrame({'target': {Timestamp('2019-03-08 10:02:24.705000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-08 12:55:21.586000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-08 13:01:36.574000'): True,
Timestamp('2019-03-08 18:13:18.041000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-08 18:54:29.286000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-09 10:16:55.969000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-09 13:00:41.357000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-09 15:51:43.340000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-09 16:37:31.487000'): True,
Timestamp('2019-03-10 14:20:40.158000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-10 15:12:52.386000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-11 08:11:57.956000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-11 12:17:35.041000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-11 13:23:43.058000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-11 20:31:03.062000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-11 20:55:30.677000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-12 10:38:44.177000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-12 12:25:37.269000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-12 13:40:54.494000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-12 18:49:28.487000'): False,
Timestamp('2019-03-13 09:58:23.547000'): True}})
```

EDIT: added dataframe sample for ease of copy/paste and recreating it in Python

Comment: Can you share a sample of the dataframe? i.e just copy/pase

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors. What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, so you're going to need to be more specific than that.

Comment: @yatu sure, added an edit

Comment: @AMC this is nor a screenshot of a code neither a screenshot of an error. This  is an illustration I've made for reader's convenience.
What is unclear about the question? How can you make a conclusion I'm asking to write a code for me with a line "will be grateful for any suggestions on how to improve it." ?

Comment: @eyeballpaul _ this is nor a screenshot of a code neither a screenshot of an error._ Did you read anything beyond the title? The exact same arguments apply here. _How can you make a conclusion I'm asking to write a code for me with a line "will be grateful for any suggestions on how to improve it." ?_ You're asking for suggestions on how to improve something, yet you haven't actually shared the actual code itself, right? Do you not see why someone could think what I did?

Comment: _EDIT: added dataframe sample for ease of copy/paste and recreating it in Python_ Thank you, that's one of the reasons why it's best not to use images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207553/discussion-between-eyeballpaul-and-amc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to look at a *forward* window, you need to use a new feature in Pandas 1.0 that allows you to do `rolling()` with a custom indexer that will let you pick a window going forward in time.

See [Dynamic window size with rolling functions](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-new-features-in-pandas-1-0-you-should-know-about-fc31c83e396b#838b) in this Medium article talking about new features in Pandas 1.0.

In order to make use of this feature, you need to define a new subclass of [`BaseIndexer`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.1/pandas/core/window/indexers.py#L34) which defines an appropriate `get_window_bounds()` method.

The `get_window_bounds()` method should return a tuple with two arrays, the first with the start offset and the second with the end offset, with one element for each row in the index.

In your case, you can use a simple `arange()` for the start offsets (start on the element itself, or the following one.) For the end offset, I used `searchsorted()` to find the index entry at or before the 1 hour interval in the future.

I implemented handling of the `closed` argument of `rolling()`, so you can use `closed="left"` to consider the current timestamp as inside the window, `closed="right"` to include an entry exactly one hour in the future as part of the window, and `closed="both"` to accept both as valid.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer

class ForwardTimewindowIndexer(BaseIndexer):
    def get_window_bounds(
        self,
        num_values=0,
        min_periods=None,
        center=None,
        closed=None,
    ):
        start = np.arange(0, num_values, dtype='int64')
        if closed not in ['left', 'both']:
            start += 1
        search_side = 'left'
        if closed in ['right', 'both']:
            search_side='right'
        end = self.index_array.searchsorted(
            self.index_array + self.window_size,
            side=search_side,
        ).astype('int64')[:num_values]
        return (start, end)
```

And you can use it with:

```
indexer = ForwardTimewindowIndexer(
    index_array=df.index,
    window_size=pd.to_timedelta('1h'),
)
df['required_col'] = df['target'].rolling(indexer).sum().astype(bool)
```

This should produce the exact result you described.

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int64_t' but got 'long'` on pandas 1.0. Any idea why?

Comment: @JuanEstevez Can you take a look at the full backtrace? Worked for me with DatetimeIndex and booleans in the series...

Comment: @JuanEstevez Sorry tried to post backtrace but looks like you've already tried it, I'll leave it here just in case, https://gist.github.com/eyebp/d99557f3d17300aa9bc7765342b16fe9

Comment: @eyeballpaul Try `np.arange(0, num_values, dtype='int64')`, or perhaps add `.astype('int64')` to the end of the `searchsorted()`, I'd say it's most likely one of those two...

Comment: @eyeballpaul Looks like it's a Windows vs. Linux thing. Anyways, updated the answer to cast everything to `int64` which I expect will solve that!

Comment: @filbranden Replacing with `start = np.arange(0, num_values, dtype='int64')` fixed it for me. Thank you! I will study this code and learn how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I actually thought of a different approach that's much simpler and doesn't require a custom indexer. (Also, should work on Pandas <1.0)

Start by creating a Series with the `'target'` values, but with the index shifted one hour earlier.

```
target = df['target'].set_axis(
    df.index - pd.to_timedelta('1h')
)
```

One way to reason about this is that this Series is indexed by the timestamp where the value *starts* affecting the result, which is one hour earlier than its original timestamp.

Next, we add the original timestamps to the index, so that we have both original and shifted timestamps. The added timestamps will have NaN values attached to them, which is adequate. We're sorting the index and dropping duplicates (which would happen if we have timestamps exactly one hour apart in the original index.)

```
target = target.reindex(
    target.index.append(df.index)
        .sort_values().drop_duplicates()
)
```

At this point, we can use `rolling('1h')` to calculate which values will see `target=True` in the previous hour (which actually means in the *next* hour in the original DataFrame.)

We'll use `closed='neither'` since it seems you're not interested in `target=True` in the exact same timestamp (and we'll assume you don't want to consider one that's exactly one hour later either. Change to `closed='right'` if you accept the one that's exactly one hour later.)

We then `sum()` to aggregate True's (`sum() is very efficient and works well with NaN's), then we replace any NaN's with zeroes, and finally convert back to booleans, so that only the non-zero entries will be set to True.

We then use `.loc[...]` to only grab the entries matching the original index, ignoring the ones shifted one hour that we only used temporarily for the calculation.

```
df['required_col'] = target.rolling(
    '1h', closed='right'
).sum().fillna(0.0).astype(bool).loc[df.index]
```

That's it! The calculation is finished. I tested this on your example DataFrames and a few more corner cases with exactly one hour intervals and it worked as expected.